# proxychains does not work with browsers (chromium, firefox) but work with curl

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, chromium, tor, proxychains

I am trying to configure proxychains4 to run browser.

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install proxychains4 tor` - to install packages (also tried to make it from repo)

`sudo nano /etc/proxychains4.conf` - to open configuration. Strict, dynamic, round_robin modes were tryed sequentially.
At the end of the file socks5 proxy was added in format `socks5  176.103.xx.xx   29xxx   username  password` right after I removed default socks4 proxy.

`sudo systemctl start tor.service` - to start tor

`sudo systemctl status tor.service` - to check tor is running

```bash
~$ sudo systemctl status tor.service
● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2023-07-01 10:26:33 +06; 1h 13min ago
    Process: 1059 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1059 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1msssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
```

`proxychains4 curl ifconfig.co/country` - to check if proxychains works. I expect to see Ukraine, because proxy server placed in Kharkiv.

```bash
~$ proxychains4 curl ifconfig.co/country
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] Dynamic chain  ...  127.0.0.1:9050  ...  176.103.60.33:29443  ...  ifconfig.co:80  ...  OK
Ukraine
```

Everything ok, for a while.

#### Firefox

`proxychains4 firefox dnsleaktest.com` to run firefox. Problems start here

```bash
~$ proxychains4 -f /etc/proxychains4.conf firefox dnsleaktest.com
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains4.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
```

Browser runs successfully. But it shows my real ip address in Kazakhstan. Surfing on browser does not generate new logs in console.

#### Chromium

```bash
~$ proxychains4 -f /etc/proxychains4.conf chromium dnsleaktest.com
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains4.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
Gtk-Message: 11:46:45.877: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
[30511:30511:0701/114645.963070:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(162)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
WARNING: Kernel has no file descriptor comparison support: Operation not permitted
[30511:30511:0701/114647.303045:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(697)] Message 0 rejected by interface blink.mojom.WidgetHost
[30511:30605:0701/114648.404437:ERROR:udev_watcher.cc(98)] Failed to begin udev enumeration.
[30637:30637:0701/114713.640413:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
```

Running chrome is also successfull, but ip is my real one. But the logs are different from firefox ones.

Question: What should I do to force browsers go to internet via proxychains?
[system info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICGUd.png)

- installed packages
- configured proxychains
- checked it works with curl
- tried several chain modes
- read tons of forums